# SharePoint Online Content Enhancement Web Service - Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have an immediate need to utilize the Microsoft Graph service (similar to the On Premise CEWS within SharePoint) called “content-events”. I’d like to be notified when new content is about to be added to the Index using the “Subscription Management” API of Graph so that I can “Add” additional crawled properties to enrich the content. I also need the content body (full text) of the document from a document library programically. What calls within the Graph API can be used to accomplish the same functionality of Content Enrichment Web Service?

Comment: Please add the code or what your have tried. This forum is not for pure code services. And current, just the https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/subscription_post_subscriptions you may refer to.

Comment: I tried to create a subscription using the “subscription management” API of Graph and then use the “Enhanced” property of Graph to apply a value as a crawled property term on the document. 
Requests to this endpoint return the following 400 Bad Request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/content-events/subscriptions
Returns:
 { "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'content-events'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "36d0028a-8657-4b1e-838b-dfc6772e8948",
            "date": "2018-10-24T17:18:32"
        }}}

Answer (score 0):

Based on my researching, **Content Enrichment is not available to SharePoint Online customers**. Due to Graph interact with O365 product, so the Graph is not suitable for your current requirement. Of course, you can submit one [feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for it first.

> https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146001/content-enrichment-for-o365

Comment: Thanks, but that post is from 2015. What has been done within the O365 space to allow a user to add enrichment to a crawl prior to being indexed like you can with an On Premise SharePoint environment using CEWS?

Answer (score 0):

Mike the contents-events service was a private internal preview that never made it out of there.
There is work being done by Microsoft Search team to consider how this will be done. But to start with basic search extensibility needs to be tackled before tackling something like this. More news will come during Build 2019.